# insert int into list

Tags: haskell

I would like to insert a int into the correct position in the sorted list. for example if I insert 2 it would in insert in the second position.

```
insert :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int
insert x [] = [x]
insert x (y:ys) = if xsy 
                 then x:y:ys else y insert x ys
```

can anyone point what's wrong. 
thanks

Comment: Basically, you're done. It remains to fix a few typos.

Comment: "can anyone point what's wrong" - I believe the compiler could tell you a thing or two about what's wrong. Learning to understand compiler errors is a great boon to programming in any language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Daniel Fischer says, you just have a few typos:

- `xsy` should presumably be `x < y`.
- You have a missing operator in `y insert x ys`; what operator do you need to prepend a value to a list? (Hint: You use it when pattern-matching the list.)
- You missed a `]` after `[Int`.
- Your indentation is wrong; `then` should be aligned at least as far as the `if`, and the `else` should be on a new line, aligned with `then`. If you're indenting with tabs, you should set your editor to indent with spaces instead (or, if you must, set it to display tabs as 8 spaces, which is what Haskell expects).

Other than that, you're good to go.